# How to start another Firefox instance on Windows?

Tags: windows, linux, firefox

How exactly can I start several Firefox instances, so that I could use several proxies?

I don't want to use Firefox add-ons, and I need to be logged in several places [via HTTPS in Firefox], but it requires several proxies (for example, I don't want to install [FoxyProxy](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/foxyproxy-standard/)).

Extra: How do I do it under Linux?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution might be to use multiple profiles.

See mozillaZine's [Command line arguments](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Command_line_arguments) on how to start Firefox with different profiles.
More info can be found in [Managing profiles](http://support.mozilla.com/en-US/kb/Managing%20profiles).

Answer (score 2):

For Windows: `firefox -no-remote`

For Linux: `/usr/bin/firefox -no-remote`

Make sure that there is no existing instance of Firefox before running this command.